# Compile protobuf-net RuntimeTypeModel to C#, not DLL

Tags: c#, .net, protobuf-net, decompiling, precompile

For protobuf-net, I need access to compiled serializers for a manually constructed `RuntimeTypeModel` in code format, not in an assembly, due to a few particularities with the build process.

Assuming that I can find a decompiler, I'm considering generating the assembly and then running the decompiler to generate the C# files. However, this is an ugly approach and I would rather avoid it.

Does protobuf-net have any support for generating the compiled models with C# output?

Answer (score 0):

No, it does not. It works at the raw IL level.

Comment: Is the `Compile` method the only location where it is generating IL? I'm considering modifying it so that it just emits C#.

Comment: @sient really no; there is a complicated "decorator" pattern in play, each emitting the IL for the steps needed. Converting it: not practical. You may want to look at protobuf-csharp-port, which is code-emit based